# Equilibrium Sequence of {c(t)}

Tags: macroeconomics

So I am currently stuck on the following problem:

Consider a representative agent model where the representative consumer has preferences given by $$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t \ln(c_t)$$ where $0<\beta<1$ is the consumer's subjective time rate of preference and $c_t$ is consumption at time $t$. The consumer is endowed with one unit of consumption good at $t = 0$. The consumption good can be stored costlessly across time. That is, consumption at $t$ follows $$x_{t+1} = x_t - c_t$$ where $x_t$ is the available consumption at the beginning of $t$ and $x_0=1$.

Solve for the equilibrium sequence of $[c_t]_{t=0}^\infty$.

Now the first thing that throws me off that is away from a traditional model is that leisure is completely missing from the consumer's preferences. Next I rearranged to find for $c_t$ which is seen from $$x_{t+1} = x_t - c_t$$ $$x_{t+1} - x_t = -c_t$$ $$x_t - x_{t+1} = c_t$$ $$-{\mathit{\Delta}}x_t = c_t,$$ but given the negativity are we summing negative values?

Comment: The Euler equation for consumption gives you consumption at all future dates given $ c_0 $, and the constraint that $ \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} c_t = x_0 = 1 $ (solve the difference equation forward, use positivity of $ c_t $ to get convergence, and then argue that the inequality has to hold as an equality at an optimal solution) then pins down a unique value of $ c_0 $. Try to do it yourself.

Comment: $\beta^{t-1} u'(c_t)dc_t - \beta^t u'(c_{t+1}) Rdc_t = 0$ which implies $u'(c_t) = \beta Ru'(c_{t+1})$ for $t = 1,2,3,....$ and where $R = 1+r$? Is this correct for general form?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct general form. In your example, you just have $ R = 1 $.